# Is there a way to pass/iterate an array as a style attribute in React?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of randomly generated Hex colors with 8 objects and i'm trying to get each hex code from the array and pass it into the backgroundColor style of a component in React

```
let colorsArr = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
            const generateColor =
                "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);

            colorsArr.push(generateColor);
        }
    }, []);
```

This returns an array like this with different values each time the page is loaded

```
["#4c9cae", "#db8e9b", "#1f78aa", "#c4c1d9", "#38b1c5", "#2a3833", "#97da7a", "#543e93", "#6cc0d4"]
```

My attempt at it was just indexing each value at each component after the for loop ends but it doesn't work and i have no actual clue and uppon researching i didnt find anything

```
const colorCheckHandler = () => {
// check if for loop has ended and array is complete
        if (colorsArr.length >= 8) {
            
            return true;
        } else {return false;}
    }
```

```
// render component
{colorCheckHandler ? 
<span style = {{
    backgroundColor: `${colorsArr[0]}`
}}
/>
: null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useEffect() hooks run after the page has mounted or rendered so your "colorArr" might be empty on the initial page load. You can provide an initial value to the "colorArr" and then change it later when the for loop in useEffect() executes after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your function. like this `colorCheckHandler()`

```
// render component
{colorCheckHandler() ? 
<span style = {{
    backgroundColor: `${colorsArr[0]}`
}}
/>
: null}
```

Comment: That gives me an error and stops the component from rendering
`':' expected
`

Comment: i mean to say call like this -> `colorCheckHandler()`  rest code remain same, anyway edited ans